# Comparing two values evaluates to false instead of true

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I'm using Node.js with Express.js and Redis. I'm recording the uptime of a site component by incrementing a redis key. I want to update the `uptimerecord:tracker` key once the current uptime > the current uptime record but somehow it's not updating it and evaluating uptimeTracker > uptimeRecordTracker with `false` even though it's true.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks!

```
  db.get("uptime:tracker", function(err, uptimeTracker) {
      db.get("uptimerecord:tracker", function(err, uptimeRecordTracker) {
          console.log("[Stats] uptimeTracker: " + uptimeTracker)
          console.log("[Stats] uptimeRecordTracker: " + uptimeRecordTracker)
          console.log("[Stats] Compare: " + (uptimeTracker > uptimeRecordTracker))
          if(uptimeTracker > uptimeRecordTracker) {
              console.log("[Stats] Tracker Records updated")
              db.set('uptimerecord:tracker', uptimeTracker)
          }
      });
  });
```

The console output:

```
[Stats] uptimeTracker: 213
[Stats] uptimeRecordTracker: 99
[Stats] Compare: false
```

Comment: ..are they strings or integers? try ``parseInt(uptimeTracker) > parseInt(uptimeRecordTracker)``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're comparing strings instead of integers, in fact:

```
"213" > "99" == false
```

while

```
213 > 99 == true
```

Try converting them to integers before doing the comparison:

```
parseInt(uptimeTracker) > parseInt(uptimeRecordTracker)
```

Comment: to have a shorter notation, you can use the unary + operator that converts its operand to a number. instead of the parseInt solution, write : +uptimeTracker > +uptimeRecordTracker

Comment: Don't forget the radix on parseInt!